# How can i configure a http proxy for apt-get?

Tags: raspbian, apt-get

I have a raspberry pi with raspbian. I have to use a http proxy now, but where can I configure the proxy?

It seems the `apt-get` ignores the `http_proxy`, which I defined like this:

```
export http_proxy="http://username:password@host:port/"
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I managed to solve it in the following way. Go to the following folder:

```
cd /etc/apt/apt.conf.d
```

Create a file named `10proxy`:

```
sudo nano 10proxy
```

Without authentication add the following line:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://yourproxyaddress:proxyport/";
```

With authentication:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://username:password@yourproxyaddress:proxyport/";
```

The `/`at the very end was important. Without it it did not work.

Answer (score 5):

If you run apt-get with sudo you have to modify `/etc/sudoers` and append

```
Defaults env_keep = "http_proxy https_proxy ftp_proxy"
```

you can edit it by calling `visudo`.

You could also use `su`, set the proxy and then run `apt-get`